# Break \printbibliography to multiple frames without [allowframebreaks]

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I am using mtheme for my Beamer presentation with XeLaTeX and Biber and I have a quite crowded bibliography. But when I try to add `[allowframebreaks]` I receive a "TeX capacity exceeded" error. I found out that this is an apparent bug with the theme (https://github.com/matze/mtheme/issues/20).

I want to modify the `\printbibliography` command so that it inserts a `\framebreak` after every five entries. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi, can I ask if you ever present your very long biblio during the talk? If not, why're you even putting it on the slides? ...

Comment: While your question in its objective is quite clear, it would be very nice if you could add a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) we can play around with. But to be honest, it seems much more reasonable to treat the cause (the `[allowframebreaks]` bug) than a symptom (namely some ad-hoc framebreaks).

Comment: Excluding the bibliography entirely is not a possible option for the slide; it will be handed to my instructor later.

I don't know how I can edit the style file to treat the `[allowframebreaks]` bug, but I suspect it will be much more difficult than adding framebreaks. All I want is to be able to add a `\framebreak` after every 5 citations

Comment: No-one suggested it was you who had to fix the bug `;-)`. You see, while I'm sure what you ask for is doable I don't think it will be exceptionally easy and it will not yield good results in all possible use cases.

Comment: Just an aside: If the only reason why you would not want to exclude the bibliography is because your instructor would like to see it later, you could just create a second document that only contains the bibliography for them to enjoy?

Comment: Yes, I understand that what I ask is not a very good practice in general. I just would like to keep using the style document as is with this workaround if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I present to you: the sledgehammer method.

Fortunately, `biblatex` allows us to hook into the very end of a bibliography entry with the bibmacro `finentry`, by default defined as `\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry}`.

We define is

```
\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\brf}
```

Where we define `\brf` as follows

```
\newcounter{bibitmctr}
\newcommand{\brf}{%
  \stepcounter{bibitmctr}%
  \ifnum\value{bibitmctr}=5%
    \setcounter{bibitmctr}{0}
    \framebreak
  \fi
}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newcounter{bibitmctr}
\newcommand{\brf}{%
  \stepcounter{bibitmctr}%
  \ifnum\value{bibitmctr}=5%
    \setcounter{bibitmctr}{0}
    \framebreak
  \fi
}

\renewbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry\brf}
\begin{document}
  \nocite{maron,geer,cicero,wilde,knuth:ct:a,moore,nussbaum,vizedom:related,worman,
          knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,knuth:ct:related,massa}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you remove your code the bibliography breaks over three pages too as you don't have a frame environment. And *with* a frame environment you need the `[allowframebreaks]` option and it is unclear if the bug doesn't appear with manual framebreak too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You might have a point there. But this seems to me to be what the OP asked for. Since the problem actually stems from the beamer theme's refusal to work with `[allowframebreaks]` that is actually the bug to be fixed, this work-around is quite the ad-hoc "solution", and does not yield pleasing results in all cases (as can be seem here: the standard page breaking yields three frames and looks, to my eye at least, slightly better).

Comment: I don't plan to write `\printbibliography` command in a frame in this environment; so @UlrikeFischer's point is valid but will not affect my condition. Maybe I should have instead asked how to append anything to the end of a bibliography entry; `\finentry` did that for me.

Comment: @moewe: I added an answer to explain what I mean.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is exactly what I said in my comment: The auto-break yields much more pleasing results.

Answer (score 2):

It is unnecessary to hard code the number of bib entries per page (which could lead to isolated entries on a page if five don't fit). If you are willing to set the bibliography as in moewes example outside of a frame it is quite enough to adjust the page geometry a bit:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame} a normal frame \end{frame}

\topskip=2cm\advance\textheight by -2cm\enlargethispage{-1cm}
  \nocite{maron,geer,cicero,wilde,knuth:ct:a,moore,nussbaum,vizedom:related,worman,
          knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d,knuth:ct:e,knuth:ct:related,massa}

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```